# Make methods of an object sent over SOAP visible

Tags: java, soap, netbeans, netbeans-6.9, netbeans-7

I'm using Netbeans to create a web application project. The IDE adds METRO2.0 libraries when I create a new web service (code first WS). The SOAP web service is well deployed in my apache Tomcat 6. However, when I send a complex type, the client couldn't access to the methods of the sended object in the client.
Say I have a class called **Person** and an operation:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "getOnePerson")
    public Person getOnePerson() {

        return new Person("MyName", "MySurname", 24);
    }
```

And the Person class:

```
public class Person {

    private String name, surname;
    private int age;

    public Person() {

    }
    public Person(String name, String surname, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }
}
```

So how may I make the client know the **Person** methods?
Thanks
EDIT: I've tried to update my XSD file by adding Pesron's attributes:

```
<xs:complexType name="person">
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:attribute name="surname" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:attribute name="age" type="xs:int" />
    </xs:complexType>
```

By adding this portion, the client knows the getter & setter of the class Person but when trying to run the program, all the getters return null (client side):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Person p = getOnePerson();
            System.out.println(p);
            System.out.println(p.getSurname());
            System.out.println(p.getName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static Person getOnePerson() {
        com.company.ws.BeanWebService_Service service = new com.company.ws.BeanWebService_Service();
        com.company.ws.BeanWebService port = service.getBeanWebServicePort();
        return port.getOnePerson();
    }
}
```

returns: 
*com.company.ws.Person@d75415
null
null*
So could you please tell me why the client doesn't know the different values of class's attribute?

Comment: I can copy the classes to the client. But is the JVM capable to resolve the address memory of every attribute? In fact, the client, creates automatically a new type called com.company.ws.Person in which there is no methods. So creating another class with the same name can cause some problems. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have found and resolves the problem:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType (name = "Person", propOrder = {"name","surname", "age"})
public class Person {
    @XmlElement(name="name",required = true)
    private String name;

    @XmlElement(name="surname",required = true)
    private String surname;

    @XmlElement(name="age",required = true)
    private int age;

//GETTER & SETTER
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As JAX-WS uses JAXB to marshal/ unmarshal objects, I recommend:

- define a XSD for Person
- generate the JAXB classes of this XSD
- use the generated Person class as the return type of your Web Service

If you're using Maven (highly recommended), then you can use the following plugin to generate the JAXB classes from a XSD:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <generatePackage>com.yourcompany.somecomponent.somepackage.jaxb</generatePackage>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Expected XSD & xjb (JAXB customization files) location: src/main/resources

Comment: OK, as I understand, the xsd file will do the mapping with the client class. Isn't it? I've found an example for sending a HashMap using <map>
  <pair>
    <key>KEY1</key>
    <value>VALUE1</value>
  </pair>
  <pair>
    <key>KEY2</key>
    <value>VALUE2</value>
  </pair>
</map>
in http://www.coderanch.com/t/415853/Web-Services/java/JAXB-mapping-HashMap. Is this what you mean?

Comment: The XSD specifies the data structures of your Web Service in a programming language neutral way. JAXB allows to marshal/ unmarshal Java POJOs to/ from XML documents conforming to the XSD. So you will still have a Person class similar to the one you've wrote by hand, not a HashMap.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I found that the IDE have already generated an xsd file to map the WS. As I understand, I have to modify this file to map the Person objects. http://hpics.li/2686848

Comment: As a rule of thumb, never manipulate a generated file by hand, especially if there is a chance that you need to re-generate the file later. I recommend to follow the approach I mentioned. Alternatively you can add the JAXB annotations to your existing Person class manually. (Java based approach)